# React-jest: some tests failed, although everything was written correctly

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to test a component using react-testing-library and still get a failed test, and don't know the reason.
Here are the two files I am working with

component file:

```
import React from "react";

const TestElements = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 data-testid="counter">{counter}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestElements;
```

test file:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import TestElements from "./TestElements";

afterEach(cleanup);

it("should equal to 0", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<TestElements />);
  expect(getByTestId("counter")).toHaveTextContent(0);
});
```

Comment: How does it fail? Please post a copy of the log/error.

Comment: I got a type error:  TypeError: expect(...).toHaveTextContent is not a function

Comment: and those are the other stuff: 
Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 file obsolete, 0 total
Time:        6.456s, estimated 8s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Answer (score 0):

The code to achieve what you are after can then be

```js
it("should equal to 0", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<TestElements />);
  expect(getByTestId("counter").innerHTML).toEqual("0");
});
```

#### Explanation:

The problem is that `toHaveTextContent` isn't a valid matcher. You can find the list of matchers [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers#common-matchers) and more information on `expect` [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect).

The functions returned by React Testing Library's `render` will return you a DOM element, you can treat it as you would in the browser (for the most part). For example, you can issue an event on them, like `click` to trigger a behaviour.

In your case, we can get the text of the element using `innerHTML`. Now the part inside the `expect(...)` is text, so we then use `toEqual` to assert it's a certain text.